# Inherit constructors from bases in parameter pack

Tags: c++11, inheritance, constructor, multiple-inheritance, variadic-templates

In C++11 it is possible to "inherit constructors":

```
struct A{  };

struct B : A{
  using A::A;
};
```

Under certain circumstances (see discussions below) it is also possible to multiple inherit constructors.

```
struct D : A, B, C{
  using A::A;
  using B::B;
  using C::C;
};
```

Finally, It is also possible to inherit generically from all the types in a parameter pack:

```
template<class... Ts>
struct D2 : Ts...{};
```

The question: **Is it possible to inherit all the constructors of the base classes generically?** Like this:

```
template<class... Ts>
struct D2 : Ts...{
   using Ts::Ts...; // ??? compiler error 
};
```

such that `struct D2<A, B, C>` is equivalent with `struct D` above.

Comment: [EWG issue 102](http://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#102), [CWG issue 1393](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1393), so I guess no sooner than C++1z

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, for `D<A, B, C>` would be equivalent to `struct D : A, B, C{using A::A; using B::B; using C::C;};`. I think it this sense Barry's answer is not equivalent.

Comment: @alfC But that's not legal either.

Comment: In works in some cases, I think it is ok if 1) all the constructors of A, B, and C have different signatures 2) all of the them have default constructors also.

Comment: The usual workaround is recursion.

Comment: @T.C., yes, since yesterday I developed a recursive derivation. It works in the basic examples but I don't know if it is equivalent because instead of a class deriving from many you have a chain of derived classes.

Comment: @alfC About as equivalent as we can get within the current spec, I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

The usual (not very pretty) workaround is recursion:

```
template<class... Ts>
struct D { };

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct D<T, Ts...>: T, D<Ts...>{
  using D<Ts...>::D;
  using T::T;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/843561403e4f2d05).

Note that under the current specification for inheriting constructors, this is not strictly equivalent to the

```
struct D : A, B, C{
  using A::A;
  using B::B;
  using C::C;
};
```

version, and may be inefficient if a constructor argument is passed by value, because the chain of inheriting constructor calls requires multiple moves (which might degenerate to copies for legacy types). [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3112fcdbc31339e).

The paper [N4429](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4429.html) addresses this and a number of other issues related to inheriting constructors, and has passed EWG review at Lenexa.

Comment: I arrived to the same conclusion except that I also created an auxiliary class that is necessary if `D` has members (and you don't want to "accumulate" them).

Answer (score 1):

No, such a thing is not possible. There is a [list of contexts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) in which pack expansion is allowed to occur, and a *using-declaration* is not one of them.

A *mem-initializer-list* is an allowed context though, so you could do something like:

```
struct A { A(int ) { } };
struct B { B(int ) { } };

template <typename... Ts >
struct D : Ts... {
    template <typename... Args>
    D(Args&&... args) : Ts(std::forward<Args>(args)...)... { }
};

int main() {
    D<A, B> d(4);
}
```

The above actually fails to compile in gcc 5.2 though ([bug 65422](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65422)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used this trick at some point when there were variadic templates but not inherited constructors yet. I think I stopped using it because of this problems: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/too-perfect-forwarding/ and the noise in the syntax it produced. **I think also this is not equivalent because it will only forward the constructor if it is allowed in all the base classes.**

Comment: @alfC Not sure why you bolded that. Of course that's true. What would you expect the inherited constructors to do differently in such a case?  Perfect-forwarding probably isn't even a good idea, as what if `A` moved-from one of the args, and then `B` gets junk? It's a non-trivial problem. But with a pack expansion used as the base classes, inheriting isn't an option - so this is what you have.

Comment: I think your solution is complementary to inheriting constructors. Yours only works if all the constructors have _common_ signatures, `struct D : A, B{using A::A; using B::B;}` will only work if A and B constructors have _different_ signatures.

Comment: @alfC No, that won't work at all, unless all the types are default constructible...

Comment: correct, different signatures and all default constructible (I just learned that). In that case your code will not work, well, unless some type conversions happen, but even then it will do something different.